# How to remove margins for RawMaterialButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is my code:

```
Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      color: Colors.red,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      child: RawMaterialButton(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 32, maxHeight:32, minWidth:32, maxWidth:32),
        onPressed: () => {},
        fillColor: Colors.indigo,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        shape: CircleBorder(),
      ),
    );
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As you see there is space (margins?) around `RawMaterialButton`. Could anyone say how to remove this space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,`

```dart
child: RawMaterialButton(
  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
  elevation: 0,
  onPressed: () => {},
  disabledElevation: 0,
  fillColor: Colors.indigo,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.add,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  shape: CircleBorder(),
),
```

[image]

More about [`RawMaterialButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RawMaterialButton-class.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use BoxConstraints.tight

```
constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(32, 32)),
```

Also, please note Rawmaterial button is obsolete. You can use textbutton or elevated button instead.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RawMaterialButton-class.html